# Mobile Push Messages not being delivered to Android

Tags: mobilepush, android, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Background:

- Using ReactNativeSDK We have iOS and Android devices registered in MC
- Sends are being reported for both in Marketing Cloud with no errors
- Push messages are being delivered fine to iOS, but not to the registered Android devices - this is the issue

We have raised a case with Support, who have resolved some issues to get us to where we are now, but will not help further because this is an implementation issue.

NB I'm not the app developer. I'm trying to help because they're not making much progress. Will do my best to answer any questions on their behalf.

If anyone has come across/resolved any similar issues I'd be keen to hear how. Any help appreciated!

Comment: There's really nothing in this message to troubleshoot. A support case is your only real option.

Comment: Thanks @Billmote. I've suggested the developer implement the example code in a standalone app to narrow down possible causes.  https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk/tree/master/example
Appreciate any advice on other steps we might try.

Comment: @BillMote, what does the SDK do if the FCM Server Key is invalid - e.g. does it log an error when it initialises??

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. We were testing using the /push/v1/messageList/ API to a list that was set to "automatically refresh upon sending".

Manually refreshing the list via the UI resulted in all registered devices receiving a test push. So it would appear that "automatically refresh upon sending" doesn't work for sends initiated by API.

Non-delivery to Android was apparently a red herring.